# Пустая страница после отправки формы

Tags: php, mysql

С чем связана пустая страница после отправки формы в случае если все условия соблюдены?

P.S В базу не пишется

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/slick-theme.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/slick.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <title>InstaTOP - Продвижение в инстаграмме</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php
    require "scripts/db.php";

    $data = $_POST;

    if ( isset($data['do_signup']) ) {

        $errors = array();

        if ( trim($data['email']) == '' ) {
            $errors[] = 'Введите почту!';
        }

        if ( $data['firstname'] == '' ) {
            $errors[] = 'Введите имя!';
        }

        if ( $data['lastname'] == '' ) {
            $errors[] = 'Введите фамилию!';
        }

        if ( trim($data['login']) == '' ) {
            $errors[] = 'Введите логин!';
        }

        if ( $data['password'] == '' ) {
            $errors[] = 'Введите пароль!';
        }

        if ( $data['password'] != $data['repeatpassword']) {
            $errors[] = 'Пароли не совпадают!';
        }

        if ( empty($errors) ) {
            $user = R::dispense('users');
            $user->email = $data['email'];
            $user->firstname = $data['firstname'];
            $user->lastname = $data['lastname'];
            $user->login = $data['login'];
            $user->phone = $data['phone'];
            $user->password = $data['password'];
            R::store($user);
            echo '<div class="register_error">Успешная регистрация</div>';
        } else {
            echo '<div class="register_error">'.array_shift($errors).'</div>';
        }
    }
?>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="authorize text-center">
            <h1 class="login">InstaTOP</h1>
            <h4 class="login">Продвижение в инстаграмме</h4>
            <h4 class="login">Регистрация</h4>
            <hr>
            <form action="register.php" method="POST">
                <input type="text" class="input" name="email" placeholder="E-Mail" value="<?php echo @$data['email']; ?>">
                <input type="text" class="input" name="firstname" placeholder="Имя" value="<?php echo @$data['firstname']; ?>">
                <input type="text" class="input" name="lastname" placeholder="Фамилия" value="<?php echo @$data['lastname']; ?>">
                <input type="text" class="input" name="login" placeholder="Логин" value="<?php echo @$data['login']; ?>">
                <input type="text" class="input" name="phone" placeholder="Телефон" value="<?php echo @$data['phone']; ?>">
                <input type="password" class="input" name="password" placeholder="Пароль">
                <input type="password" class="input" name="repeatpassword" placeholder="Повторите пароль">
                <hr>
                <button class="login" name="do_signup" type="submit">Регистрация</button><br><br>
                <a class="register" href="login.php">Уже зарегистрированы? - Авторизоваться.</a>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Сломанный редирект:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/slick-theme.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/slick.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <title>InstaTOP - Продвижение в инстаграмме</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php

    require "scripts/db.php";

    $data = $_POST;

    if ( isset($data['do_signup']) ) {

        $errors = array();

        if ( trim($data['email']) == '' ) {
            $errors[] = 'Введите почту!';
        }

        if ( $data['firstname'] == '' ) {
            $errors[] = 'Введите имя!';
        }

        if ( $data['lastname'] == '' ) {
            $errors[] = 'Введите фамилию!';
        }

        if ( trim($data['login']) == '' ) {
            $errors[] = 'Введите логин!';
        }

        if ( $data['password'] == '' ) {
            $errors[] = 'Введите пароль!';
        }

        if ( $data['password'] != $data['repeatpassword']) {
            $errors[] = 'Пароли не совпадают!';
        }

        if ( empty($errors) ) {
            $user = R::dispense('users');
            $user->email = $data['email'];
            $user->firstname = $data['firstname'];
            $user->lastname = $data['lastname'];
            $user->login = $data['login'];
            $user->phone = $data['phone'];
            $user->password = $data['password'];
            R::store($user);
            header('Location: http://akciapdd.ru/instatop/index.php');
        } else {
            echo '<div class="register_error">'.array_shift($errors).'</div>';
        }
    }
?>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="authorize text-center">
            <h1 class="login">InstaTOP</h1>
            <h4 class="login">Продвижение в инстаграмме</h4>
            <h4 class="login">Регистрация</h4>
            <hr>
            <form action="register.php" method="POST">
                <input type="text" class="input" name="email" placeholder="E-Mail" value="<?php echo @$data['email']; ?>">
                <input type="text" class="input" name="firstname" placeholder="Имя" value="<?php echo @$data['firstname']; ?>">
                <input type="text" class="input" name="lastname" placeholder="Фамилия" value="<?php echo @$data['lastname']; ?>">
                <input type="text" class="input" name="login" placeholder="Логин" value="<?php echo @$data['login']; ?>">
                <input type="text" class="input" name="phone" placeholder="Телефон" value="<?php echo @$data['phone']; ?>">
                <input type="password" class="input" name="password" placeholder="Пароль">
                <input type="password" class="input" name="repeatpassword" placeholder="Повторите пароль">
                <hr>
                <button class="login" name="do_signup" type="submit">Регистрация</button><br><br>
                <a class="register" href="login.php">Уже зарегистрированы? - Авторизоваться.</a>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Что-то, где-то сломалось. Покажите лог ошибок с сервера и консоль браузера.

Comment: @Visman , может ли файл db.php иметь ошибку 500, а не пустое содержимое? http://akciapdd.ru/instatop/scripts/db.php

Comment: Покажите лог ошибок с сервера и консоль браузера.

Comment: @Visman, это очень странно, но убрав комментарий сверху и снизу страницы все заработало...

Comment: @Visman, а как вывести ошибки на экран? Теперь не работает редирект..

Comment: В вашем коде я не вижу редиректа. Если редирект вы делаете с помощью `header('Location:...`, то ни чего выводить нельзя `Помните, что функцию header() можно вызывать только если клиенту еще не передавались данные. То есть она должна идти первой в выводе, перед ее вызовом не должно быть никаких HTML-тегов, пустых строк и т.п. Довольно часто возникает ошибка, когда при чтении кода файловыми функциями, вроде include или require, в этом коде попадаются пробелы или пустые строки, которые выводятся до вызова header(). Те же проблемы могут возникать и при использовании одиночного PHP/HTML файла. `

Comment: @Visman, страница имеет такой вид, в чем проблема, почему не редиректит и каким образом можно решить эту проблему?

Comment: @user273992 добавьте `exit;` после `header('Location..')`

Comment: @Alex, в таком случае не будут передаваться переменные, предположим через GET, а так же сессии, верно?

Comment: @user273992 будут если `header()` на тот же сайт

Comment: @Alex, exit в конце скрипта не редиректит, а оставляет на этой же странице только без содержимого, остается только пустой градиентный фон.

Comment: @Alex - можете сами посмотреть: http://akciapdd.ru/instatop/register

Comment: всё работает ведь